# MPMoviePlayerController: Rewind back to start?

Tags: objective-c

how to I stop a Video from playing and go back to start?

```
videoPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0.0 ; // This doesnt work as expected. 


[videoPlayer stop]  // Shows just a "blank" page
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[videoPlayer stop];
```

Answer (score 4):

This works as well

```
videoPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0;
[videoPlayer pause];
```

Answer (score 1):

DO this:

```
   if(videoPlayer)
   {
      [videoPlayer stop];
      myMoviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0.0;
      [videoPlayer play];
   }
```